AWS Amplify @primaryKey and @index
Hello:  I need some help.  I am going to pull my hair out.  I have been building an AWS Amplify App.  I build the database using the visual editor and pulled the app into my local environment.  I am using VS Studio Code.  I edited the graphQl database in VS Code to add some more types and pushed to Amplify.  This all worked and I had my app working.  However, I could not get the information to return by date.  It was always a return by the primary key (ID).  I have found a very significant amount of information that says use @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["field"]).  This is what is in the amplify documentation as well.  However, when I edit my schema to include this next to the ID amplify does not accept it when I push it up and nothing works.  I have also tried @index(name: "byfield", queryField: "tableByField")  Nothing is working or being accepted.  I am building a preventative maintenance application and the table is Service Dates.  I am pasting my schema here for that table. The date is set in my application to just auto fill from the time it was created, so I could just use the createdAt attribute that is automatically generated by AWS.  Anyway,  Someone please help me return my query results by date so they make sense.
type ServiceDate @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["Date"])
  Date: AWSDate!
  checkedBelt: Boolean!
  checkedOil: Boolean!
  passedInspection: InspectionEnum
  pictureKeys: String
  Notes: String
  equipmentID: ID! @index(name: "byEquipment")
}

type ServiceDate @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["Date"])
  Date: AWSDate!
  checkedBelt: Boolean!
  checkedOil: Boolean!
  passedInspection: InspectionEnum
  pictureKeys: String
  Notes: String
  equipmentID: ID! @index(name: "byEquipment")
}

